# Can you pass a parameter in SQL referencing a specific data set?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a database, and in the database I want to reference a specific data set. When a user queries it I want it to only return data related to the user, as opposed to returning similar data sets not related to them. I want to use something like a keyword argument, and I know sql has a `where` clause but it is limited and doesn't enable one to return a specific set of data.

```py
self._headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'}
```

The example above references a specific instance, and that's what I want to do within my database.

```py
from cmath import e
from http.client import OK
from logging import exception
from socket import if_nameindex
import psycopg
import datetime
from config import *


class profiles:

    def commercial_profile(self):
        conn = None

        try:
            with psycopg.connect(
                dbname = dbname,
                user = user,
                password = password,
                host = host,
                port = port
            ) as conn:

                with conn.cursor() as cur:

                    total_streaming_plays = '''WITH temp AS (
                    SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_spotify
                    UNION ALL
                    (SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_tidal)
                    UNION ALL
                    (SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_soundcloud)
                    UNION ALL
                    (SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_youtube)
                    UNION ALL
                    (SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_youtube_music)
                    ) SELECT SUM(plays) AS total_plays 
                    FROM temp;'''

                    cur.execute(total_streaming_plays) 
                    for records in cur:
                        print(records[0] * 2)  

                conn.commit()

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        finally:
            if conn is not None:
                conn.close()
```

In my above query where it is `SELECT  artist, plays FROM machine_spotify`, I would like to have `SELECT artist={username}, plays FROM machine_spotify` referencing username's data within the database. A `where` clause would work but it would be limiting.

Comment: This make no sense. If you want to return all the rows that have the `artist` equal to the `username` then you will need a `where` clause. If you are trying to achieve something else you will need to provide an example with data.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I tried using a ````where```` clause,  ````SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_spotify WHERE artist = 'machine_profile.stage_name.jheinke0'```` but I get a ````unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'````  error. what I'm trying to query the database dynamically.

Comment: Is this: `machine_profile.stage_name.jheinke0` an actual `artist` name? Looks more a table name.column name reference. Pretty sure the error is coming from `print(records[0] * 2)`  where `records[0]` is `None` so you are getting `None * 2` and the error. I would working out the query in `psql` until you get something that returns the results you want and then transferring it to Python.

Comment: yeah, you are right the ````records[0]```` was causing the ````NoneType```` error.  the reason I wrote it like this ````machine_profile.stage.name.jheinke0```` was because i wanted to dynamically query jheinke0 which is an artist in the database but I realized there is no need for the first part.

Comment: what I want to do is calculate the total no. of streams of a particular artist in the database. As oppose to calculating all the streams in the database. I want it to dynamically happen. when a user/artist is logged in.

Comment: Understood, but you need to create a working query. The fact that `records[0]` is returning `None` would indicate you don't have one. Simplify the problem by working directly on the database using the Postgres command line client `psql` to get a query that returns what you want. Run the static query in `psycopg2` to verify it works there and then build the dynamic portion.